# Issues debugging infix grammar in pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I wrote this script in order to parse statements with a syntax similar to prolog, treating connectives as operators with precedence:

```
import pyparsing as pyp

alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
alphabet = alphabet + alphabet.upper()

symbol = pyp.Word(alphabet)

predicate = symbol + "(" + pyp.ZeroOrMore(symbol + ",") + symbol + ")"

parenthetic = pyp.Forward()

pyp_formula = pyp.infixNotation((predicate | parenthetic),
       [
           (pyp.oneOf('~'), 1, pyp.opAssoc.RIGHT),
           (pyp.oneOf(','), 2, pyp.opAssoc.LEFT),
           (pyp.oneOf(';'), 2, pyp.opAssoc.LEFT),
           (pyp.oneOf('::'), 2, pyp.opAssoc.LEFT),
           (pyp.oneOf('->'), 2, pyp.opAssoc.LEFT),
           (pyp.oneOf(':-'), 2, pyp.opAssoc.LEFT),
           (pyp.oneOf('--'), 1, pyp.opAssoc.LEFT),
           (pyp.oneOf('.'), 1, pyp.opAssoc.LEFT),
       ])

parenthetic << "(" + pyp_formula + ")"
```

When I run

```
parse = pyp_formula.parseString('d(A, D), e(D) :- f(A), g(D); h(D).')

parse_list = formula_parse.asList()

print(parse_list)
```

I get that "d(A, D), e(D)" has not even been split into two predicates and "f(A), g(D); h(D)" is treated as a single terminal within a non-terminal.

```
[[[['d', '(', 'A', ',', 'D', ')', ',', 'e', '(', 'D', ')'],
':-', [['f', '(', 'A', ')', ',', 'g', '(', 'D', ')'],
';', 'h', '(', 'D', ')']], '.']]
```

I've tried several alternatives but I don't seem to be able to get the right parse.

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to define `parenthetic`, `infixNotation` does that for you. And if you `pyp.Group` your `predicate` expression, then the symbol and symbol args will get grouped for you. pyparsing also has the `delimitedList` helper as a short cut for `expr, expr, expr`: use `pyp.delimitedList(expr)`. The default delimiter is ',', but you can define other delimiters. Lastly, with a list of operators this long, it is likely that you will have performance issues with any non-trivial parse - add a call to `ParserElement.enablePackrat()` to turn on an internal parsing cache.

Here is how your code looks with these changes:

```
import pyparsing as pyp
pyp.ParserElement.enablePackrat()

alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
alphabet = alphabet + alphabet.upper()

symbol = pyp.Word(alphabet)

predicate = pyp.Group(symbol + "(" + pyp.delimitedList(symbol) + ")")

pyp_formula = pyp.infixNotation(predicate,
       [
           (pyp.oneOf('~'), 1, pyp.opAssoc.RIGHT),
           (pyp.oneOf(','), 2, pyp.opAssoc.LEFT),
           (pyp.oneOf(';'), 2, pyp.opAssoc.LEFT),
           (pyp.oneOf('::'), 2, pyp.opAssoc.LEFT),
           (pyp.oneOf('->'), 2, pyp.opAssoc.LEFT),
           (pyp.oneOf(':-'), 2, pyp.opAssoc.LEFT),
           (pyp.oneOf('--'), 1, pyp.opAssoc.LEFT),
           (pyp.oneOf('.'), 1, pyp.opAssoc.LEFT),
       ])

pyp_formula.runTests(
    '''
    d(A, D) -> h(D).
    d(A, D), e(D) :- f(A), g(D); h(D).
    '''
    )
```

And the results:

```
d(A, D) -> h(D).
[[[['d', '(', 'A', 'D', ')'], '->', ['h', '(', 'D', ')']], '.']]
[0]:
  [[['d', '(', 'A', 'D', ')'], '->', ['h', '(', 'D', ')']], '.']
  [0]:
    [['d', '(', 'A', 'D', ')'], '->', ['h', '(', 'D', ')']]
    [0]:
      ['d', '(', 'A', 'D', ')']
    [1]:
      ->
    [2]:
      ['h', '(', 'D', ')']
  [1]:
    .


d(A, D), e(D) :- f(A), g(D); h(D).
[[[[['d', '(', 'A', 'D', ')'], ',', ['e', '(', 'D', ')']], ':-', [[['f', '(', 'A', ')'], ',', ['g', '(', 'D', ')']], ';', ['h', '(', 'D', ')']]], '.']]
[0]:
  [[[['d', '(', 'A', 'D', ')'], ',', ['e', '(', 'D', ')']], ':-', [[['f', '(', 'A', ')'], ',', ['g', '(', 'D', ')']], ';', ['h', '(', 'D', ')']]], '.']
  [0]:
    [[['d', '(', 'A', 'D', ')'], ',', ['e', '(', 'D', ')']], ':-', [[['f', '(', 'A', ')'], ',', ['g', '(', 'D', ')']], ';', ['h', '(', 'D', ')']]]
    [0]:
      [['d', '(', 'A', 'D', ')'], ',', ['e', '(', 'D', ')']]
      [0]:
        ['d', '(', 'A', 'D', ')']
      [1]:
        ,
      [2]:
        ['e', '(', 'D', ')']
    [1]:
      :-
    [2]:
      [[['f', '(', 'A', ')'], ',', ['g', '(', 'D', ')']], ';', ['h', '(', 'D', ')']]
      [0]:
        [['f', '(', 'A', ')'], ',', ['g', '(', 'D', ')']]
        [0]:
          ['f', '(', 'A', ')']
        [1]:
          ,
        [2]:
          ['g', '(', 'D', ')']
      [1]:
        ;
      [2]:
        ['h', '(', 'D', ')']
  [1]:
    .
```